# XNA Frame rate 30 to 60

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, frame-rate

WP 7/8 + xna games by default set to 30 FPS,  I would like to know If i set it to 60 FPS , any disadvntages / Performence issues / bugs / any other. becuase i always wants to play/develop the game in 60 fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 SDK sets XNA to 30 FPS because the screen on Windows Phone 7 Devices has a 30hz refresh rate.  This means the screen refreshes at 30 times a second.  If you are drawing 30 times a second and you refresh 30 times a second your at the optimal rate of smoothness for that device.

The reason most people aim for 60 (or on my gaming PC, 120) is because most monitors have a 60hz refresh rate (some are now 120hz).  *If your FPS is HIGHER than your refresh rate you won't notice see anything else* except for possible an effect known as "Screen-Tearing" which is what happens when you render more frames in a second than your screen refreshes.

In other words imagine you draw to the screen two times and then your screen refreshes once, why did you bother drawing the second time?  You waste battery life, cpu usage, and gpu usage when you render faster than the refresh rate of a device.  So my advice to you if your sticking with XNA is that you stick with 30 FPS because the older devices won't get any benefit by having more frames rendered and if anything you'll get graphical anomalies like screen tearing.

If you plan to target higher-end (and newer) windows phone 8 devices, drop XNA, go the Direct3D route and use Microsoft's "DirectX Toolkit" because it includes XNA's "graphics functions" like spritebatch but in C++ instead of C#.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add a few points to Strife's otherwise excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14722225/165500).

- Physics simulations are generally more stable at higher FPS. Even if your game runs at 30 FPS, you can run your physics simulation at 60 FPS by doing two 1/60th of a second updates each frame. This gives you a better simulation, but at a high CPU cost. (Although, for physics, a *fixed* frame-rate is more important than a *high* frame rate.)
- If you poll input 30 times per second, instead of 60, you will miss extremely fast changes in input state, losing some input fidelity.
- Similarly, your frame rate affects the input-output latency. At a lower frame-rate it will take longer for input change to be reflected on-screen, making your game feel less responsive. This can also be an issue for audio feedback - particularly in musical applications.

Those last two points are only really important if you have a very twitchy game (*Super Hexagon* is a fantastic example). Although I must admit I don't know how fast the touch input on WP7/8 is actually refreshed  - it's difficult information to find.